# Programmatically create spring beans for each bean/configuration/... of a given type

Tags: java, spring

I would like to create programmatically a bunch of different beans for each bean (or configuration or similar) extending a given base class.
What makes it more difficult is, that the beans should be already available at the phase the autowiring of other beans takes place.

Is the some kind of spring base class or interface (something like BeanPostProcessor) I could implement to achive that?

Use case is similar to create a bean for each data source in context.

Comment: If i understand right, you wanna create different implementation for different beans. Why don't you want to just use `@Qualifier` and multiple `@Bean` for each of them?

Comment: Because I want to create the Beans programmatically and not manually. For example for the eight configuration beans C1, C2, C3, C4, C5, C6, C7, C8 extending baseclass B and each with different implementation and configuration I need additionally the beans L1, L2, L3, L4, L5, L6, L7, L8 and E1, E2, E3, E4, E5, E6, E7, E8 and R1, R2, R3, R4, R5, R6, R7, R8 and Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4, Q5, Q6, Q7, Q8.
And at some place in the application I want to refer e.g. L3 by using the qualifier, at an other place to L5 and so on